# Upgrade spring mvc to spring 6 stops mapping static resources folder to index.html

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, staticresource, tomcat10, welcome-file

I have a spring mvc application and I am upgrading that to spring 6. The upgrade was successful but having issues with static resources. I have help files in the application and I have mapped `/help/**` url to `/help/`. I am using tomcat version 10.1.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/help/**" location="/help/" />
```

When I open URL `http://localhost:8080/app/help` it shows 404. While using spring 5 it was displaying index.html from the help directory but after upgrading to spring 6 it's not mapping index.html.

If I use `http://localhost:8080/app/help/index.html` then it opens the page correctly.

Is there any other configuration required in spring 6 that will map index.html in folder/subfolders for static resources?

I have tried mapping *.html to the default servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After the above changes in the `web.xml` file it shows the page correctly at URL `http://localhost:8080/app/help` But I have also swagger documentation so when I open `http://localhost:8080/app/swagger-ui/index.html` then it shows 404.

I want `http://localhost:8080/app/help` to open the help file with index.html and map index.html for subfolders and `http://localhost:8080/app/swagger-ui/index.html` to open swagger documentation.